# Splitting string in multiple variable fields using regex using python

Tags: python, pandas, parsing

I have a dataframe were each row of a certain column is a text that comes from some bad formatted form where each 'field' is after the the 'field title', an example is:

| col |
| --- |
| Name: Bob Surname: Ross Title: painter age:34 |
| Surname: Isaac Name: Newton Title: coin checker age: 42 |
| age:20 Title: pilot Name: jack |
| this is some trash text Name: John Surname: Doe |

As from example, the fields can be in any order an some of them could not exist.

What I need to do is to parse the fields so that the second line becomes something like:

```
{'Name': 'Isaac','Surname': 'Newton',...}
```

While i can deal with the 'pythonic part' I believe that the parsing should be done using some regex (also due to the fact that the rows are thousands) but I have no idea on how to design it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
x = df["col"].str.extractall(r"([^\s:]+):\s*(.+?)\s*(?=[^\s:]+:|\Z)")
x = x.droplevel(level="match").pivot(columns=0, values=1)

print(x.apply(lambda x: x[x.notna()].to_dict(), axis=1).to_list())
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {"Name": "Bob", "Surname": "Ross", "Title": "painter", "age": "34"},
    {
        "Name": "Newton",
        "Surname": "Isaac",
        "Title": "coin checker",
        "age": "42",
    },
    {"Name": "jack", "Title": "pilot", "age": "20"},
]
```

Comment: thank you @Andrej . Unfortunately i think i made a mistake in the examples since i forgot to clarify that in the rows there is also other text that shouldn't be parsed that is before this text, i'll add on more example row

Comment: The only things i know are: the possible field titles, the last stopping word (after that one nothing should be parsed) and that the trash text is before the 'form' or after the stopping word.

Comment: @Tsadoq With your new example the output is `[{'Name': 'Bob', 'Surname': 'Ross', 'Title': 'painter', 'age': '34'}, {'Name': 'Newton', 'Surname': 'Isaac', 'Title': 'coin checker', 'age': '42'}, {'Name': 'jack', 'Title': 'pilot', 'age': '20'}, {'Name': 'John', 'Surname': 'Doe'}]`. Is it missing something?

Comment: Nope, my mistake, i have another question, in the case of 'name: surname: ross' the s of surname is pasted as field for name, how could i solve this? @andrej-kesely

Comment: @Tsadoq Try to change the regex to `r"([^\s:]+):\s*(.*?)\s*(?=[^\s:]+:|\Z)"`

Comment: This seems to work, thank you very much. One more question, how should i write the regex if i wanted to use only the 'field titles' i want (eg, parse only "name: bob" and "surname: ross" but not "age: 34" or others. In short, how can i restrict what you wrote to only some "start strings" and not all the ones of  tye type \s:

Comment: @Tsadoq It's better to remove the not wanted keys afterwards from dictionary than creating complicated regex.

Comment: I accepted your answer @Andrej! i was wondering, how should i modify your regex so that the field (so for name: 'bob') is matched until a punctuation character (so that if i have "name: bob, that is a handsome guy" only bob is taken)? I can change the separator between name and bob to something non punctuation so not to have any conflict